# Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system when using certbot-auto

Tags: https

When I using this command in `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`:

```
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly -d '*.poemhub.top' \
--manual --preferred-challenges dns \
--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
./certbot-auto has insecure permissions!
To learn how to fix them, visit https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-auto-deployment-best-practices/91979/
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.
```

I search from internet and found the new version of cert-bot only support Debian or RHEL,why? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

certbot-auto now only for centos 6

cerbot for centos 7 & 8

remove certbot-auto and install certbot , follow : https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-apache

or [enter link description here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx) for NGINX

Comment: why give up certbot-auto? @yanto

Comment: links are 404 now..

Answer (score 1):

When I using this command in Amazon linux 2

```
sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit [this](https://certbot.eff.org/) to check for other alternatives.